# Vega-Lite : specific mark color for multi-line chart

Tags: vega-lite

How can I set a line color stocked in a data field ?
In Vega I did :

```
marks :[
 {
   encode: {
     enter: {
       ...
       stroke: {field: "color"}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a similar way in Vega-Lite ?

Comment: I have reframed my question and got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001047/vega-lite-stroke-color-value-from-data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `color` encoding with the `line` mark. There are a few examples on the vega-lite website; one relevant one is the [Multi Series Line Chart](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/line_color.html):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "description": "Stock prices of 5 Tech Companies over Time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I use this exemple as base. It group data by the "symbol" field but do not take color value stored in this field to stroke the line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not certain what you're asking. It might help to open another question with a full example of what you're trying to do, rather than just a snippet.

Comment: This is a useful resource to think through when writing your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Give us the information we need to be able to help you!

Comment: Sorry, I have ask an other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001047/vega-lite-stroke-color-value-from-data) . Thank for advises