# Vega-Lite : stroke color value from data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vega-lite

In Vega it is possible to take a color value from data, like that : [example in Vega](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwAVgAMuxREgpG1fFoBM+w1ELo1axjOpbtipZDXo8mHAG0lCFAIEKgZdFRkLUgfdgAbKJtQyAp0ONZkWC0A0NDgSAAPLQMoAE9LEsg49HZkOOjMeSh4bjjuACdogGIAMx79fUgAXyTc-KKcAEYmyHKcAGY3KGra+pxIRubWju6+gd1h0bzCyxm5sEnKlbqGhS22zvXe-oHDwLGThbOtSaWqmpu602kBaD12L0GI3exwmYFE3xwogAHDNrmsoMDQTsnntXlDciFxq4EWALCjlgD0Rs7iDto8oM99m8CUFPmAAGwk9mcimrW4zLH0yCMvFHQlsgDsJIsUt5gIxNMF4KZ+JZRJw5NmPx5-z5QMVdOVouh4thAE5pX80fz7tiGbjIe4WWB1WBKucyajKdF2AawU99LjmWq2dMylpRPMvXqoL6BYaA7og6qCa6LCSkWHdfLIHHbUKuoGXsHU2yo+Gpha5VS87T-Qyi46TazYfCKzp09WfX67cLGwcUx9YX8PW3szWewX+yWh1odeckbLx934-W+0ni4OYVol+dJkvreta0rE8mxS2tJrzuzNYfY5PutOt6atFWtYi33fcw-T5uTQBdd4hiUf8bEgBA0kybJ3mCXJIHCSJoiKMUYlKQgonWQhuCcPAFBNSB2nQZwMJUdRNBQtRuAwJwtHyLwfGiWIEhpHpGDqNQkOGIDRlg5IEJIrUULwNCBLiJxkHQToUMI4johMMxcJQmRGHgEi8HaDIUIAL2QdpuC0dTNPwyjqLkHA6O8XwoCYxIoFY9jonKYDQmcsBQI8dACig-wYMgDo2JkXCj24AgqJpCDmPWIpB3yfzkEC6IEh6RSoAigSnJAsCMHaABrLIfLyfDhPQ6JqD01hCDwglIB6PTUFo5s7PQVSgpdRqjH46JYF0tisnPEJPEsxiamY-qjDK7gKvYc5l0a1yXJQ7K8ug51eJZVCSvWMSZESdq7Lq2jBoY9ZuvaXqZ2q+KWjUEi1udSB4rwXSGudarYXyNLOJmey4g4qKLte98XXA+BIMcli2N+8Hn3u2B1O4HLbpqyG-vzLjXpCeaWSxlyAKAkCQGAoA/)

Is there a way to do this with Vega-Lite ? [example in Vega-Lite](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/AQbwUMnARAJAzgYwBYFMC2BDaAuGyAXAgB3hwHpyA3VAc0wDpaBLA5AVwCMHmB7cpGizU6mALQAbVqmoAmBgCt4vAHbQANBCjQAJqiQAnZsQJ81eaABFMBTMF40DwACrN0qBhq2RoAd2Y6bLjAAKwADGGaUPiozLSEwbIRUdo6Nth44NE+KpjuwbrpADLM8ARe2TBUmBLs+sEA2t7ZINAAHsGRMACeiV3QiLwSvAYFAMQAZhMREdAAvimVrR14AIzqPcEAzCEbA0Mj41MzYfOLLe2Je71r-YPDoxaT0zNnzdHL29fBq7sw94cnsdXgt3lBPngACzfKEADj2AMeMGeJzelUgENCMOAsnh-wOSOgKJB5w+lzwADZsRSqfiHkcXrNQejQOTgAB2bGyTl0wHI4FM0ngtl46A3YCrWn7elAxmnZnozEATi5f2lfKJAvlmjBGLZ-XFuIRBPGEWBaMVbPWmyhW2NMuRZpeFqWbNk2Nh1vVhLGTsFutZK2AdptEpVvJ9fu1Acx0NDIXdEdNYXNCtdQbVhrj3uTqaFeqDUvFsJ5OaeUZdFyDpfFq1LiNzzrTVeCovFFNFDfLKab+cDwXDYuCkMHXcdPaZYIAus1m9AsAYANbBLLZaAEbrEVAFKQqbezjZQZrQVAqQY6ZgqWgrsFs1eVaATZioCQ6AodPvrzfbiwAR3YmAqKYtimDQ0Bgs2Pjive0SPs+r4FL0n4bluBT-oBwE2MwYEQUKZagAGcEvm+FgNp+Eh0KeJHACo7ASBIyHfrg0AqLw6CXjU4GVHMs5aHMQA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the `scale` to `null` in your color property.

```
"encoding": {
      "x": ...,
      "y": ...,
      "color": {
        "field": "color",
        "legend": null,
        "type":"nominal",
        "scale": null
      }
    }
```

> To directly encode the data value, the scale property can be set to
>   null.

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#disable

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @DrWoodMan great!